How to initilize logical qubits stabilizer states in a fault-tolerant way
I have what might be an elementary question for experts.
Suppose I wish to carry out fault tolerant quantum computation, with an error correcting code such as the 7-qubit code or the 5-qubit code (of course the transversal gate set is limited here), or some other code. The first step would be to initialize each block of 7 (or 5) physical qubits into a state corresponding to logical $|0\rangle_L$. My question is how, does one do this in a fault-tolerant way, using the minimum number of ancillas? Do new techniques like flag qubits offer any advantage? Is there a simple recipe for fault-tolerant initialization for an arbitrary CSS code, or an arbitrary stabilizer code?
